# Why won't my curses box draw?

Tags: python, draw, curses

I am toying with curses and I can't get a box to draw on the screen.
I created a border which works but I want to draw a box in the border

here is my code

```
import curses 

screen = curses.initscr()

try:
    screen.border(0)
    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 20, 5, 5)
    box1.box()
    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [curses docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html):

> When you call a method to display or erase text, the effect doesn’t
> immediately show up on the display. ...
>
> Accordingly, curses requires that you explicitly tell it to redraw windows, using the  **refresh()** method of window objects. ...

You need `screen.refresh()` and `box1.refresh()` in correct order.

Working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses 

screen = curses.initscr()

try:
    screen.border(0)

    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 20, 5, 5)
    box1.box()    

    screen.refresh()
    box1.refresh()

    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses 

screen = curses.initscr()

try:
    screen.border(0)
    screen.refresh()

    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 20, 5, 5)
    box1.box()    
    box1.refresh()

    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

You can use `immedok(True)` to automatically refresh window

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses 

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.immedok(True)

try:
    screen.border(0)

    box1 = curses.newwin(20, 20, 5, 5)
    box1.immedok(True)

    box1.box()    
    box1.addstr("Hello World of Curses!")

    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 13):

The suggested answer is more complicated than necessary.  Rather than use [**newwin**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-newwin), if you use [**subwin**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-subwin), it shares memory with the original window, and will be repainted without additional work.

Here is the original program modified to do that (a one-line change):

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()

try:
    screen.border(0)
    box1 = screen.subwin(20, 20, 5, 5)
    box1.box()
    screen.getch()

finally:
    curses.endwin()
```