# How to print inline after input using curses

Tags: python, input, printing, curses

I want to receive input by prompt with the following structure:

```
-----------------------------
|                           |
| Digit your name:[]        |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

where '[]' is the input cursor.

The code that i made  (not working) with raw input is:

```
print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('| {:67s} |'.format(''))
print('| {:67s} |'.format(input('Digit your name:')))
print('| {:67s} |'.format(''))
print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

How can I make it working with `curses`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in curses you need to have a main funtion where you put in the stdscr as an argument, like this:

```
import curses


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.getch()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

And the stdscr.getch() just waits for the user to press any key.

Then you can print out a string on the text with the `stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Digit your name:")`. The first two arguments are the `y` and `x` coordinates. so then it will look like this

```
import curses


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Digit your name:")
    stdscr.getch()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Then if you want a kind of `input`, you need `curses.echo()`, which will just echo your input. And then `stdscr.getstr(0, 0)`. But those two arguments are where you want the user to write. But if you run it:

```
import curses


def main(stdscr):
    curses.echo()
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Digit your name:")
    stdscr.getstr(0, len("Digit your name:"))


curses.wrapper(main)
```

You then need to say `stdscr.addstr(0, len("Digit your name:") + 1)`

And if you want to make a box [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838994/why-wont-my-curses-box-draw) is a link.

---

I hope i could help you.
And remember. You can't do this in pycharm editor. You need to do it in the terminal